# memory usage doesn't match variable sizes (Python)

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

Good morning. I got a question about memory usage and variable size. It might be a basic problem but any advise will be appreviated.

I loaded **112.4MB** pickle file with following Python code

```
import pickle

def open_dict(path_filename):
    a_file = open(path_filename, "rb")
    output = pickle.load(a_file)
    return output

features_dicts = open_dict("./files/others/features_dicts.pkl")
```

However, variable inspector of Jupyter Notebook says the size of **features_dicts** is **384B** and I found that about **124MB** of machine memory is taken with this process.

What I was expecting is that the sizes of features_dicts and used machine memory are the same **112.4MB**. Could anyone explain me or share me a link that solve my question?

I would also like to know how to release memory usage as much as possible with this situation.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What kind of pickled object? Could you tell me name of library or name of class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The file contains defaultdict object from collections (a python library).

Comment: That object is not specially behavior on memory size. You can confirm object size on memory with `sys.getsizeof`. I don't know how Jupyter analyse amount of memory usage, but this method must be able to confirm directly.